# How to post data as &parameter=value pair in Angularjs to a servlet

Tags: angularjs

I want to post data to a servlet in `key=value` pair, not in `json` format in angularjs.  Here's my code:

```
$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'login.do?mode=registration',
    data : {
        firstname : $scope.firstname,
        lastname : $scope.lastname,
        email : $scope.email,
        password : md5.createHash($scope.password)
    },
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).success(function(data){
    $location.path("/login");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `$httpParamSerializer` in your controller and use it:

```
var requestData = {...} // Your object

$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'login.do?mode=registration',
    data : $httpParamSerializer(requestData),
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).success(function(data){
    $location.path("/login");
});
```